# Trying to embed custom YouTube iFrame into Joomla module

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I have some custom code which randomises a joomla video, this works fine outside of Joomla as can be seen at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dtorr1981/cha2w7cu/1/), however when the code is placed into a Joomla custom module and published the videos do not randomise as can be seen [here](https://www.outyego.com/staging) under the module heading FAB PLACES TO GO ON OYG (2).

For testing I have disabled Cloudflare plus JCH and Jotcache, but the same video loads everytime the page loads. I am seeing a JS error in the console...

```
(index):1045 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
    at onPlayerReady ((index):1045)
    at M.h.G (www-widgetapi.js:48)
    at Y.h.o (www-widgetapi.js:92)
    at Y.h.H (www-widgetapi.js:105)
    at Wa.g (www-widgetapi.js:81)
    at Oa.f (www-widgetapi.js:70)
```

Any ideas how I can get this working? I;ve been looking at getting it working for some time now and am completely stuck. The JS is inline between  tags.

Comment: The 2nd link you provided still goes to the JSFiddle. I dont know why, but you're using the `lodash` library, so my guess is that it's not being loaded on your site, hence the `_` console error.

Comment: It was the lodash library causing the issue. I have used num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11); This has fixed the issue.

Comment: Please would you mind adding this as a proper answer below and marking it as accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the lodash library causing the issue. I have used

```
num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
```

This has fixed the issue.